# `grep` ignoring line breaks

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos

I have been using Ventura for about two weeks.  Commands that worked yesterday do not work today.

My procedure: edit each .gpx file created without line breaks by a Garmin eTrex 30.  Put each tag on its own line so that a mapping application I use will accept it.  Then to see the time periods each file tracks,

```
for GPX in *gpx; do                                 
  echo $GPX
  grep time $GPX | head -1
  grep time $GPX | tail -1
  wc $GPX
  echo "======="
done
```

This has worked fine until today.  Now, it looks like there are still no line breaks in any file—including the ones created another way that always had line breaks.  If I open a file in TextEdit, each tag is on its own line as I expect. If I check with `od -xc`, I see that the line breaks are \n and there are no \r.

I exited Terminal and all other programs (except Finder), closed all windows, and restarted.  Logged in, opened Terminal, `cd` to the directory, and tried again. Same result.

What happened?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Some odd glitch, perhaps in TextEdit, appended a **huge** portion of the pre-edited file to the end of the edited version in **two** of the files.  That line was so big, of course, that I could not see the single lines from the `head` when those two files were the last two in the `for` loop.

Once I discovered that, I deleted that line, and the error did not recur.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.